# Responsive image map

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I have an existing image map in a responsive html layout. Images scale according to browser size, but the image coordinates are obviously fixed pixel sizes. What options do I have to resize the image map coordinates?

Comment: This question is not about a geographical map but the <map> html tag

Comment: Check out the [image-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-map) plugin. It works with Javascript, Node, and jQuery

Comment: As an alternative, you can use an SVG image. I recommend reading [Using SVG as an Alternative To Imagemaps](http://thenewcode.com/696/Using-SVG-as-an-Alternative-To-Imagemaps)

Comment: Sounds like what we want is the ability to upload a JPEG or similar to an app that lets you specify map locations on the image (such as at image-map dot net) - in the background, this produces an SVG file that is essentially transparent. We then want the map to apply to the SVG and to render the SVG on top of the JPG in the web browser. As the browser resizes the JPG, the SVG is also resized and the SVG is always the one invoked when clicking the image map. Any suggestions on any of the parts of this?

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted in 2011

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64716067/2397550

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**For responsive image maps you will need to use a plugin:**

https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps (No longer maintained)

Or

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/imagemap-resizer

---

> No major browsers understand percentage coordinates correctly, and all
>   interpret percentage coordinates as pixel coordinates.

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/html/imagemaps

And also this page for testing whether browsers implement

http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/IMG/resizeimg3.html

Comment: is any of this still relevant?  could you provide an update please?

Comment: @Malachi Yes this is still relevant

Comment: thank you Tom, we were having a discussion on a question on CodeReview,  now I wish I could remember the question....

Comment: @Tom this works only for one image..if we place another image then its not working for second and third image etc...just check it..

Comment: I've found an online generator tool that uses SVGs which all major browser understand https://imagemapper.noc.io

Comment: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/html/imagemaps worked, and how easy it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 73):

You can also use SVG instead of an image map. There is [a tutorial](https://thenewcode.com/760/Create-A-Responsive-Imagemap-With-SVG) on how to do this. Sample below, imported from [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLbpmsaj/).

```css
.hover_group:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#projectsvg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 77%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#projectsvg svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure id="projectsvg">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

    <!-- set your background image -->
    <image width="1920" height="1080" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" />

    <!-- create the regions -->
    <g class="hover_group" opacity="0">
      <a xlink:href="https://example.com/link1.html">
        <text x="652" y="706.9" font-size="20">First zone</text>
        <rect x="572" y="324.1" opacity="0.2" fill="#FFFFFF" width="264.6" height="387.8"></rect>
      </a>
    </g>
    <g class="hover_group" opacity="0">
      <a xlink:href="https://example.com/link2.html">
        <text x="1230.7" y="952" font-size="20">Second zone</text>
        <rect x="1081.7" y="507" opacity="0.2" fill="#FFFFFF" width="390.2" height="450"></rect>
      </a>
    </g>
  </svg>
</figure>
```

Comment: By far the best solution in 2020. Try this code generator to make it super simple. https://imagemapper.noc.io/#/

Comment: This has to be the top best responsive solution in 2020.

Comment: @BrettDonald did you build the generator?

Comment: @belgac no, i didn't build it, i just found it

Comment: @BrettDonald does this support non rectangle area?

Comment: @Eric, yes the basic technique supports all SVG shapes including paths – for example check out http://thenewcode.com/696/Using-SVG-as-an-Alternative-To-Imagemaps and https://adventistchurch.com/about/. However, the code generator I linked to will only generate rectangular areas.

Comment: just came here to say that the imagemapper.noc.io tool and this answer should be top 1 on 2023.

Answer (score 42):

I found a no-JS way to address this. The hit areas will be rectangular unless you change the border-radius to make circular or oval areas.

First of all, make sure your image is in a div that's relatively positioned. Then put the image inside this div, which means it'll take up all the space in the div. Finally, add absolutely positioned div's under the image, within the main div, and use percentages for top, left, width, and height to get the link hit areas the size and position you want.

I find it's easiest to give the div a black background color (ideally with some alpha fading so you can see the linked content underneath) when you're first working, and to use a code inspector in your browser to adjust the percentages in real time, so that you can get it just right.

Here's the basic outline you can work with. By doing everything with percentages, you ensure the elements all stay the same relative size and position as the image scales.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <img src="background-image.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
  <a href="/link1"><div style="position: absolute; left: 15%; top: 20%; width: 12%; height: 8%; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);"></div></a>
  <a href="/link2"><div style="position: absolute; left: 52%; top: 38%; width: 14%; height: 20%; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);"></div></a>
</div>
```

Use this code with your code inspector in Chrome or your browser of choice, and adjust the percentages (you can use decimal percentages to be more exact) until the boxes are just right. Also choose a `background-color` of `transparent` when you're ready to use it since you want your hit areas to be invisible.

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you

Comment: Nice solution! UIkit uses the same technique for their markers: https://getuikit.com/docs/marker

Comment: Brilliant solution, thanks for sharing! I am using this in a mobile app and it solves the issue of different screens.

Comment: Not working when sent as part of an HTML email.

Comment: @RahulKumar A lot of style-heavy HTML breaks on emails. I never tested it on an HTML email, and I'm sure it depends on the provider to some degree, as a lot of HTML rewriting goes on for all clients that render HTML emails. In what way is it not working, and did you inspect the code to see if some of the div tags didn't survive? Or perhaps the email client doesn't support relative positioning? Something along those lines is bound to be the issue.

Comment: Great solution! exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 39):

[Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin](http://www.mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html) by Matt Stow

Comment: Just and FYI for eveyrone... I've found that this works well, but not inside an accordion. I am using Bootstrap 3 and if you do not load the page with the accordion open on the image, when you open the accordion, the image map is not there unless the browser window is resized.

Comment: @jasonflaherty could you trigger a resize event to force the map to show? `$(window).trigger('resize');`

Comment: @SteveMeisner I haven't tried that... but wouldnt that force a refresh?

Comment: @jasonflaherty nope! It just "triggers" the resize event on the element you bind (the `window` in this case). Good luck.

Comment: Just created the super basic, but handy Drupal module using this plugin: https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_imagemaps

Answer (score 21):

I ran across a solution that doesn't use image maps at all but rather anchor tags that are absolutely positioned over the image. The only drawback would be that the hotspot would have to be rectangular, but the plus is that this solution doesn't rely on Javascript, just CSS. There is a website that you can use to generate the HTML code for the anchors: http://www.zaneray.com/responsive-image-map/

I put the image and the generated anchor tags in a relatively positioned div tag and everything worked perfectly on window resize and on my mobile phone.

Comment: Nice find! Thanks for contributing to this list

Comment: I cannot upvote this naswer enough!! An ***excellent*** tutorial; comprehensive and easy to undertsand. One should read it all, but of particular interest is http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/scripting.html

Comment: This is a really simple yet nice solution if the to-be-clicked-area is rectangle.

Comment: This is so awesome.  Worked for me as well with a DNN site.  As Jeffrey stated, I just dropped the <img> and the generated html inside of a relative positioned div.  Thanks!

Comment: Posted this myself because I didn't see it had already been included here. This was wonderful and ought to be the accepted answer imho.

Answer (score 12):

The following method works perfectly for me, so here's my full implementation:

```
<img id="my_image" style="display: none;" src="my.png" width="924" height="330" border="0" usemap="#map" />

<map name="map" id="map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="774,49,810,21,922,130,920,222,894,212,885,156,874,146" href="#mylink" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="649,20,791,157,805,160,809,217,851,214,847,135,709,1,666,3" href="#myotherlink" />
</map>

<script>
$(function(){
    var image_is_loaded = false;
    $("#my_image").on('load',function() {
        $(this).data('width', $(this).attr('width')).data('height', $(this).attr('height'));
        $($(this).attr('usemap')+" area").each(function(){
            $(this).data('coords', $(this).attr('coords'));
        });

        $(this).css('width', '100%').css('height','auto').show();

        image_is_loaded = true;
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    });


    function ratioCoords (coords, ratio) {
        coord_arr = coords.split(",");

        for(i=0; i < coord_arr.length; i++) {
            coord_arr[i] = Math.round(ratio * coord_arr[i]);
        }

        return coord_arr.join(',');
    }
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        if (image_is_loaded) {
            var img = $("#my_image");
            var ratio = img.width()/img.data('width');

            $(img.attr('usemap')+" area").each(function(){
                console.log('1: '+$(this).attr('coords'));
                $(this).attr('coords', ratioCoords($(this).data('coords'), ratio));
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

David Bradshaw wrote a nice little library that solves this problem. It can be used with or without jQuery.

Available here: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/imagemap-resizer

Comment: Confirmed for working in latest versions of Chrome/IE/FF as of this comment.

Comment: Worked great for me, super simple interface too

Answer (score 8):

consider to use this image mapper

https://imagemapper.noc.io/#/ | [github](https://github.com/pageballoon/imagemapper) | [alternative link](https://imagemapper.pageballoon.com/)

its SVG based and its responsive and

it have good wizards to build the map

its simple enough for the page because it use no library

Comment: saved my bottom :) thanks

Comment: It's awesome! Excellent tool!

Answer (score 6):

Working for me (remember to change 3 things in code):

- previousWidth (original size of image)
- map_ID (id of your image map)
- img_ID (id of your image)

HTML:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <img id="img_ID" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0865e7bad648eab23c7d4a843144de48?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" usemap="#map" border="0" width="100%" alt="" />
</div>
<map id="map_ID" name="map">
<area shape="poly" coords="48,10,80,10,65,42" href="javascript:;" alt="Bandcamp" title="Bandcamp" />
<area shape="poly" coords="30,50,62,50,46,82" href="javascript:;" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" />
<area shape="poly" coords="66,50,98,50,82,82" href="javascript:;" alt="Soundcloud" title="Soundcloud" />
</map>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var ImageMap = function (map, img) {
            var n,
                areas = map.getElementsByTagName('area'),
                len = areas.length,
                coords = [],
                previousWidth = 128;
            for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                coords[n] = areas[n].coords.split(',');
            }
            this.resize = function () {
                var n, m, clen,
                    x = img.offsetWidth / previousWidth;
                for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                    clen = coords[n].length;
                    for (m = 0; m < clen; m++) {
                        coords[n][m] *= x;
                    }
                    areas[n].coords = coords[n].join(',');
                }
                previousWidth = img.offsetWidth;
                return true;
            };
            window.onresize = this.resize;
        },
        imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('map_ID'), document.getElementById('img_ID'));
    imageMap.resize();
    return;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7EyT/154/

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [image-map](https://github.com/clarketm/image-map) plugin on Github. It works both with vanilla JavaScript and as a jQuery plugin.

```
$('img[usemap]').imageMap();     // jQuery

ImageMap('img[usemap]')          // JavaScript
```

Check out the [demo](https://www.travismclarke.com/imagemap/).

Answer (score 3):

I come across with same requirement where, **I wants to show responsive image map which can resize with any screen size and important thing is, i want to highlight that coordinates**.

So i tried many libraries which can resize coordinates according to screen size and event. And i got best solution(jquery.imagemapster.min.js) which works fine with almost all browsers. Also i have integrated it with [Summer Plgin](https://github.com/summerstyle/summer) which create image map.

```js
 var resizeTime = 100;
 var resizeDelay = 100;    

$('img').mapster({
        areas: [
            {
                key: 'tbl',
                fillColor: 'ff0000',
                staticState: true,
                stroke: true
            }
        ],
        mapKey: 'state'
    });

    // Resize the map to fit within the boundaries provided

    function resize(maxWidth, maxHeight) {
        var image = $('img'),
            imgWidth = image.width(),
            imgHeight = image.height(),
            newWidth = 0,
            newHeight = 0;

        if (imgWidth / maxWidth > imgHeight / maxHeight) {
            newWidth = maxWidth;
        } else {
            newHeight = maxHeight;
        }
        image.mapster('resize', newWidth, newHeight, resizeTime);
    }

    function onWindowResize() {

        var curWidth = $(window).width(),
            curHeight = $(window).height(),
            checking = false;
        if (checking) {
            return;
        }
        checking = true;
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var newWidth = $(window).width(),
                newHeight = $(window).height();
            if (newWidth === curWidth &&
                newHeight === curHeight) {
                resize(newWidth, newHeight);
            }
            checking = false;
        }, resizeDelay);
    }

    $(window).bind('resize', onWindowResize);
```

```css
img[usemap] {
        border: none;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-imagemapster@1.2.10/dist/jquery.imagemapster.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://discover.luxury/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Cities-With-the-Most-Michelin-Star-Restaurants-1024x581.jpg" alt="" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="777, 219, 707, 309, 750, 395, 847, 431, 916, 378, 923, 295, 870, 220" href="#" alt="poly" title="Polygon" data-maphilight='' state="tbl"/>
    <area shape="circle" coords="548, 317, 72" href="#" alt="circle" title="Circle" data-maphilight='' state="tbl"/>
    <area shape="rect" coords="182, 283, 398, 385" href="#" alt="rect" title="Rectangle" data-maphilight='' state="tbl"/>
</map>
```

Hope help it to someone.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want to resort to JavaScript, here's an image slicing example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cbzrK

As you scale the window, the clown image will scale accordingly, and when it does, the nose of the clown remains hyperlinked.

Comment: Image links are all broken.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, you can use jQuery to adjust the ranges proportionally I think.
Why do you use an image map by the way? Can't you use scaling divs or other elements for it?

Comment: while the exact solution would work with scaled divs, the image map is "content managed" and does allow for any sort of region. Thanks, I'll check out jquery for this.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Orland's answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32870380/462781

Combined with Chris' code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12121309/462781

If the areas fit in a grid you can overlay the areas by transparent pictures using a width in % that keep their aspect ratio.

```css
    .wrapperspace {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }
    .mainspace {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapperspace">
 <img style="float: left;" title="" src="background-image.png" width="100%" />
 <div class="mainspace">
     <div>
         <img src="space-top.png" style="margin-left:6%;width:15%;"/>
     </div>
     <div>
       <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="space-company.png" style="margin-left:6%;width:15%;"></a>
     </div>
  <div>
   <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="space-company.png" style="margin-left:6%;width:10%;"></a>
   <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="space-company.png" style="width:20%;"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You can use a margin in %. Additionally "space" images can be placed next to each other inside a 3rd level div.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason none of these solutions worked for me. I've had the best success using transforms.

```
transform: translateX(-5.8%) translateY(-5%) scale(0.884);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a javascript version of the solution Tom Bisciglia suggested.

My code allows you to use a normal image map. All you have to do is load a few lines of CSS and a few lines of JS and... BOOM... your image map has hover states and is fully responsive! Magic right?

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[usemap]');
images.forEach( function(image) {
    var mapid = image.getAttribute('usemap').substr(1);
    var imagewidth = image.getAttribute('width');
    var imageheight = image.getAttribute('height');
    var imagemap = document.querySelector('map[name="'+mapid+'"]');
    var areas = imagemap.querySelectorAll('area');

    image.removeAttribute('usemap');
    imagemap.remove();

    // create wrapper container
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add('imagemap');
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, image);
    wrapper.appendChild(image);

    areas.forEach( function(area) {
        var coords = area.getAttribute('coords').split(',');
        var xcoords = [parseInt(coords[0]),parseInt(coords[2])];
        var ycoords = [parseInt(coords[1]),parseInt(coords[3])];
        xcoords = xcoords.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        ycoords = ycoords.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        wrapper.innerHTML += "<a href='"+area.getAttribute('href')+"' title='"+area.getAttribute('title')+"' class='area' style='left: "+((xcoords[0]/imagewidth)*100).toFixed(2)+"%; top: "+((ycoords[0]/imageheight)*100).toFixed(2)+"%; width: "+(((xcoords[1] - xcoords[0])/imagewidth)*100).toFixed(2)+"%; height: "+(((ycoords[1] - ycoords[0])/imageheight)*100).toFixed(2)+"%;'></a>";
    });
});
```

```css
img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}

.imagemap {position: relative;}
.imagemap img {display: block;}
.imagemap .area {display: block; position: absolute; transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;}
.imagemap .area:hover {box-shadow: 0px 0px 1vw rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

```html
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/TwmCyCX.jpg" width="2000" height="2604" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="Zirconia Abutment" title="Zirconia Abutment" href="/" coords="3,12,199,371" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Gold Abutment" title="Gold Abutment" href="/" coords="245,12,522,371" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="CCM Abutment" title="CCM Abutment" href="/" coords="564,12,854,369" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="EZ Post Abutment" title="EZ Post Abutment" href="/" coords="1036,12,1360,369" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Milling Abutment" title="Milling Abutment" href="/" coords="1390,12,1688,369" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Angled Abutment" title="Angled Abutment" href="/" coords="1690,12,1996,371" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Temporary Abutment [Metal]" title="Temporary Abutment [Metal]" href="/" coords="45,461,506,816" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Fuse Abutment" title="Fuse Abutment" href="/" coords="1356,461,1821,816" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Lab Analog" title="Lab Analog" href="/" coords="718,935,1119,1256" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Transfer Impression Coping Driver" title="Transfer Impression Coping Driver" href="/" coords="8,1330,284,1731" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Impression Coping [Transfer]" title="Impression Coping [Transfer]" href="/" coords="310,1330,697,1731" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Impression Coping [Pick-Up]" title="Impression Coping [Pick-Up]" href="/" coords="1116,1330,1560,1733" shape="rect">
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[usemap]');
images.forEach( function(image) {
    var mapid = image.getAttribute('usemap').substr(1);
    var imagewidth = image.getAttribute('width');
    var imageheight = image.getAttribute('height');
    var imagemap = document.querySelector('map[name="'+mapid+'"]');
    var areas = imagemap.querySelectorAll('area');

    image.removeAttribute('usemap');
    imagemap.remove();

    // create wrapper container
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add('imagemap');
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, image);
    wrapper.appendChild(image);

    areas.forEach( function(area) {
        var coords = area.getAttribute('coords').split(',');
        var xcoords = [parseInt(coords[0]),parseInt(coords[2])];
        var ycoords = [parseInt(coords[1]),parseInt(coords[3])];
        xcoords = xcoords.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        ycoords = ycoords.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        wrapper.innerHTML += "<a href='"+area.getAttribute('href')+"' title='"+area.getAttribute('title')+"' class='area' style='left: "+((xcoords[0]/imagewidth)*100).toFixed(2)+"%; top: "+((ycoords[0]/imageheight)*100).toFixed(2)+"%; width: "+(((xcoords[1] - xcoords[0])/imagewidth)*100).toFixed(2)+"%; height: "+(((ycoords[1] - ycoords[0])/imageheight)*100).toFixed(2)+"%;'></a>";
    });
});
```

```css
img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}

.imagemap {position: relative;}
.imagemap img {display: block;}
.imagemap .area {display: block; position: absolute; transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;}
.imagemap .area:hover {box-shadow: 0px 0px 1vw rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

```html
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/TwmCyCX.jpg" width="2000" height="2604" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="Zirconia Abutment" title="Zirconia Abutment" href="/" coords="3,12,199,371" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Gold Abutment" title="Gold Abutment" href="/" coords="245,12,522,371" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="CCM Abutment" title="CCM Abutment" href="/" coords="564,12,854,369" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="EZ Post Abutment" title="EZ Post Abutment" href="/" coords="1036,12,1360,369" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Milling Abutment" title="Milling Abutment" href="/" coords="1390,12,1688,369" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Angled Abutment" title="Angled Abutment" href="/" coords="1690,12,1996,371" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Temporary Abutment [Metal]" title="Temporary Abutment [Metal]" href="/" coords="45,461,506,816" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Fuse Abutment" title="Fuse Abutment" href="/" coords="1356,461,1821,816" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Lab Analog" title="Lab Analog" href="/" coords="718,935,1119,1256" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Transfer Impression Coping Driver" title="Transfer Impression Coping Driver" href="/" coords="8,1330,284,1731" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Impression Coping [Transfer]" title="Impression Coping [Transfer]" href="/" coords="310,1330,697,1731" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Impression Coping [Pick-Up]" title="Impression Coping [Pick-Up]" href="/" coords="1116,1330,1560,1733" shape="rect">
</map>
```

Comment: Nice. is it for just one image map? My app has 30 image maps. Named ImgMap0 to ImgMap29. can you handle this case?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

responsive width && height

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var ImageMap = function(map, img) {
      var n,
        areas = map.getElementsByTagName('area'),
        len = areas.length,
        coords = [],
        imgWidth = img.naturalWidth,
        imgHeight = img.naturalHeight;
      for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
        coords[n] = areas[n].coords.split(',');
      }
      this.resize = function() {
        var n, m, clen,
          x = img.offsetWidth / imgWidth,
          y = img.offsetHeight / imgHeight;
        imgWidth = img.offsetWidth;
        imgHeight = img.offsetHeight;
        for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
          clen = coords[n].length;
          for (m = 0; m < clen; m += 2) {
            coords[n][m] *= x;
            coords[n][m + 1] *= y;
          }
          areas[n].coords = coords[n].join(',');
        }
        return true;
      };
      window.onresize = this.resize;
    },
    imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('map_region'), document.getElementById('prepay_region'));
  imageMap.resize();
  return;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more content showing the differences between your code and  [Niente0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31540457/241211) from 2015?