# Flexible HTML map in a browser

Tags: html, dictionary, responsive-design

I'm trying to build responsive HTML design in a new project. Everything is fine except HTML map. I discovered the way of dynamic generation of an HTML map as well as a background PNG image, so server side flexibility is not a problem. But is there a way to get client flexibility (by means of CSS, HTML or JS)?

Comment: what do you mean by "HTML map", could you provide an example of what you would like it to look like? An example on another site perhaps?

Is this a geographical map or image map or site map??

Comment: Sorry, I thought it have to be clear enough... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: There's a similar question here that you might like to read 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844399/responsive-image-map

Comment: Yes, that is it. At the moment I think JS is the only one solution for me...

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question again))) Maybe my solution would be useful for someone...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    GLOBAL_ARRAYCOORDS= new Array();
    GLOBAL_WIDTH=1;
    GLOBAL_ARRAYAREAS= new Array();

    function getglobal(){ 
        GLOBAL_ARRAYAREAS = document.body.getElementsByTagName("AREA");
        GLOBAL_WIDTH= 600; //document.getElementById("mapimage").naturalWidth;
        for(var i = 0; i < GLOBAL_ARRAYAREAS.length; i++) {
            GLOBAL_ARRAYCOORDS[i]= GLOBAL_ARRAYAREAS[i].coords;
        }
    }

    function scaleArea() {   
        for(var i = 0; i < GLOBAL_ARRAYAREAS.length; i++) {
            ii=i+1;
            rescale= document.getElementById("mapimage").width/GLOBAL_WIDTH ;
            sarray=GLOBAL_ARRAYCOORDS[i].split(",");      
            var rarray =new Array();
            for(var j = 0; j < sarray.length; j++) {
                rarray[j]=parseInt(sarray[j])*rescale;  
                rarray[j]=Math.round(rarray[j]);
            }
            GLOBAL_ARRAYAREAS[i].coords=rarray.join(",");
        }
    }

    window.onresize = function() {
        scaleArea();
    };
</script>

<img src="/catalog/europe.png" id="mapimage" usemap="#sueurope" onload="getglobal(); scaleArea();" />
<map id="sueurope" name="sueurope">
    <area alt="ru" coords="296,1, 296,8, ..." href="/catalog/ru" shape="poly"/>
    <area ...
</map>
```

**GLOBAL_WIDTH** is hard coded because **naturalWidth** is not supported by Opera and IE. I cannot use **width** as well because map appears scaled and I have to know absolute width of the **europe.png**.
So, now map is completely flexible! Thanks to John S. Urban for [his research](http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/IMG/resizeimg.html).