# using padding-top to keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, math, padding

/Hi,

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio/12121309#12121309) when looking for a way to keep the ratio of my pictures however I can't figure out a way to calculate accuratly the ratio of my pictures.

In this post he used 56.25% to make a ratio of 16/9, while I understand the maths (100/16*9), It doesn't seem to be the case if the height is larger than the width. any idea on how I should calculate that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flip your ratio

- 177.77777...% = 9/16 (vertical/portrait)
- 56.25% = 16/9 (horizontal/landscape)

Comment: Hi, cimmanon, thanks for your help. I thought of that but I can't put 177% in padding-top, isn't there something missing to those maths ?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't.  A `padding-top: 100%` would give you a square.  Anything smaller than 100% creates a landscape box and anything larger than 100% creates a portrait box.

Comment: Oh sorry, I had my misunderstanding of the padding propriety. Thanks a lot !