# Create a responsive layout 3 x 3 grid of 9 circles

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I've been trying to create an HTML / CSS layout of 9 circles in a 3 x 3 grid.

I'd like the layout to be responsive so that the layout would sit centrally on a large screen (but not have any vertical scroll) and then scale down to sit nicely on tablet / mobile screens too.

This is a picture of the kind of thing I'm trying to achieve (minus the bottle in the bottom corner!)

[image]

I've put my very poor effort on [codepen](http://codepen.io/bradfields/pen/vbanl) - Let's say I'm no CSS master.

This example has got a fixed width container so it's not responsive. When I try setting just a height all the circles get stretched.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hard to be responsive when it's hard coded to 1000px wide.  This is what you're looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a **pure CSS** solution, you could use `vh` [Viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) for the `#container` to specify its dimensions base on the viewport height.

Here is my attempt to achieve this:

**Sass** version:

```css
html { height: 100%; }

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide the vertical overflow */
}

#container {
  max-width: 90vh;    /* = 90% of the height of initial containing block */
  max-height: 90vh;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gold;
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  .row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33.33%;
    font: 0/0 a;    /* Hide the white space between inline(-block) elements */

    .circle {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 3%;
      width: 27.33%;
      padding-bottom: 27.33%;
      background-color: #333;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/Lwspk)**. *(Resize the panel/window horizontally and vertically)*

I should note that it doesn't have a fully [browser support](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units), but it works on most modern web browsers.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is brilliant, you've even fixed the circle sizing and added some space between them.  This will give me a great starting point to do what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Tzx2E/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ZkD5v/

HTML:

```
<div id="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle{border:1px solid black;border-radius:50%;width:33%;float:left;margin:0;padding:0;}
.row{clear:left;}
```

Either:

JS:

```
$('.circle').height($('.circle').width());
```

Or:

CSS:

```
.circle{padding-top:33%;}
```

Comment: The OP is not asking for a JS solution.

Comment: He doesn't explicitly say not to use JS either.  While your mentioned padding solution is likely better, then you can't add content to the circles. Editing...

Comment: Thanks for your work @J.A.Streich  I may end up using the other answer above, but i've had a look at your code and the way you did it and you've still taught me something so much appreciated.