# How to calculate the intrinsic ratio for a given image dimension

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am somehow head blocked to figure this out but is there an easy mathematical way to determine the intrinsic ratio for a given image lets say e.g. w 580 h 650 to get to a ratio like  3/4, 4/3, 5/6, 16/9  etc pp. Best regard Ralf

Comment: For what purpose would this be used?

Comment: I wanted to give Team Sass's Toolkit a spin to set the intrinsic ratio for sets of images to prevent reflowing.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Are you using it for this technique:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio ?

Comment: yep i want to calculate the ratio to use it in the following intrinsic mixin: https://github.com/Team-Sass/toolkit#intrinsic-ratios .They use the exact same method like in the link you've posted.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to reduce the fraction all the way down to the smallest amount, you just need to produce a decimal.  All that's going on there is division:  `7/8` gives the same results as `35/40` because Sass doesn't understand fractions anyway.

Comment: That basically means i might use, if i take the example w 580px h 650px,the value 0.89230769 as the ratio? so in general it's just width/height?

Comment: Yeah (or the reverse).  Their examples would have been a little less ambiguous if they'd used spaces (`7 / 8` vs `7/8`).

Comment: cool! thanks! i'll give it a shot when i am back home...