# Calculate css style value from another value?

Tags: css

I would like to calculate some value depending on other value. For example:

```
.my-div {
  width: 50px;
  height: calc(width * 2)
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: With pure CSS no. You can use SASS or LESS, or JS.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio

Comment: Well this is a good solution. But actually I want to calc other properties, not only width/height.
Now I see it's impossible with pure CSS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) on `calc`

This is an experimental feature, and would be possible- eg:

```
.my-div {
  width: 50px;
  height: calc(50px * 2);
}
```

However in this case as width is already known it would provide little value.

Typically in such circumstances you may be best relying on a library such as jQuery (or vanilla JS).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in CSS, however CSS-preprocessors like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) make it possible. Quite frankly this is one of many reasons why css-preprocessors have been developed.

I recommend you check the sites for more information.

Comment: But will it re-calc height if width is dynamically changed?

Comment: It doesn't, it simply generates to CSS. If you want the height to be dynamically changed according to width and the ratio should remain the same then I recommend you check the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12121309/3233450) @cimmanon mentioned. No need to use javascript when something can be done with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2015, you can achieve this with pure CSS using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) :

```
.my-div {
  --width: 50px;
  width: var(--width);
  height: calc(var(--width) * 2);
}
```