# Make a image in division responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am having images in carosuel effect which keeps images in division.I want to make images responsive.despite of adding

```
class="img-responsive"
```

to img tag the image is not giving responsive effect can any one help me? and also I wanted to know if there is any way to make division responsive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsively change div size keeping aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is,

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
.img-responsive {
//insert css for 980 width lower
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width : 400px) {
.img-responsive {
//insert css for 700 width lower
//css will not work at with lower than 400px
}
}
</style>
```

NOTE you can change the value of max width depending on what with you want to change your div. also you can set a min-width to determine what minimum width will the css take effect

cheers