# CSS maintain the ratio based on height

Tags: css, less

How to keep correct ratio (1:1.67 - e.g. `width:300px/height:500px`) of inner `div` in responsive environment where its height is 90% of outer (containing) `div`’s height?
Preferably using CSS/LESS only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div is that what you mean?

Comment: Play around with the dimensions http://jsfiddle.net/QNjxw/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsively change div size keeping aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio)

Comment: @Zach Saucier - In that example inner width is given as a percentage of outer div's width and then height managed through padding-bottom. I need it other way around. - Height given as a percentage (90%) of outer div's width and then width determined as 60% of inner div's height!

Comment: The technique to keep aspect ratio with CSS (linked in comments above) is based on the width of the element. You can't use that technique if you want to keep aspect ratio based to the height of element.

Comment: @ web-tiki I am sure you can with the help of LESS variables.

Comment: @zzzzBov yes, padding-top percentages are relative to width, but I don't have width but height. So it isn't a duplicate!

Comment: @Zel, can you add some more details (preferably images) to show what exactly you're looking for. It's hard to tell from the way you've phrased things.

Comment: I am not used to LESS so I can't say, (Even though I doubt a LESS stylesheet can retrieve height of an element and have actions on elements according to that height). I was just saying that your question wans't a duplicate of the ones linked above;

Comment: @web-tiki I agree with you - this is a different question altogether. I love that 'bottom-padding standing in for height' responsive technique and I use it all the time, but this Q is based on height. ;-)

Comment: @web-tiki re:LESS - I didn't mean to retrieve height of an element. I was hoping I could save 90% as a LESS variable and then use it to calculate inner div's width, maintaining the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The top and bottom padding of an element are relative to its width so you can use that to maintain it.

I made a little demo of this pretty recently here: http://jsbin.com/lizopahu/11/edit

Comment: That works when inner width is given as a percentage of outer div's width and then height managed through padding-bottom. I need it other way around. - Height given as a percentage (90%) of outer div's width and then width determined as 60% of inner div's height!