# Is there a possibility to scale vertically with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scale

This code only scales horizontally:

```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="box col-xs-3"></div>
       <div class="box col-xs-3"></div>
       <div class="box col-xs-3"></div>
       <div class="box col-xs-3"></div>
    </div>
```

The height should also be scalable, someone knows how to do this with bootstrap?

The width and height are the same here:

[image]

After resizing window the width and height are not the same anymore:

[image]

Comment: Scalable? What does that mean here? Divs expand to their contents by default.

Comment: I want a box to change his height when his width changes.

Comment: I found solution in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
.box {height: 10%;}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .box {height: 15%;}
}
@media (max-width: 959px) {
    .box {height: 20%;}
}
```

Your breakpoints should match what you're using for Bootstrap, of course. The problem here is that the contents of each `.box` may exceed their heights. This is rather non-standard.

Comment: The problem is when I use percentages, the height of the box stays at 0. I think thats because it's a div and not an image for instance.