# Create square divs using susy-grid

Tags: sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

Is it possible to have `@include span(3 of 12)` return in pixels instead of a %?

I'm trying to create square elements, and I want the height of this element to be equal to its width.

```
.myElement {
  width: span(3 of 12)
  height: span(3 of 12)
}
```

Of course this causes height to be a %, which is really a % of its parent container, so it is not equal to the width! Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I bet this is impossible, since it would be like a dynamic stylesheet...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsively change div size keeping aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not impossible at all — just tricky (if you want a fluid square).

```
// Static width/height is simple
.square-a {
  @include span(2 static);
  height: span(2 static);
}

// Fluid takes a bit more work
.square-b {
  @include span(2);
  height: 0;
  // %-Padding is always relative to parent width
  padding-top: span(2);
  position: relative;

  // Inner element positioned to fit space
  span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Here's a [demo of both](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8240ad47510dcd8cd531).