# Resize background image using :after/:before psuedo

Tags: css, background

I've made my background image responsive in my :after psuedo but not able to control the height responsiveness so I end up with a big white space at the bottom of my image.

My CSS:

```
.element:after {
    content:'';
    background:url('http://i57.tinypic.com/4kdytv.png') no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    height:284px;
    display:block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w6amht6o/

I've seen a couple other questions like this but none of them discuss making the height responsive.  I seen you could try something like "background-width:100% 100%;" but this did not work for me.

Let me know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: What do you mean by "making the height responsive"?

Comment: Well I mean the image is responsive as it sits in the fiddle.  If you inspect element though you will see a huge white space below the image because of the set height.  I am trying to avoid that white space.

Comment: Doesn't `background-size: cover;` do what you want? See: http://jsfiddle.net/w6amht6o/1/

Comment: That doesn't actually scale the image.  The way I have it works perfect just need to remove the white space below the image from the height being set to 284px.

Comment: Ok I see what you want now. What you are wanting is quite difficult because the psuedo element will have no idea what height to be unless you set it to be a specific height. You can either a. Use an `<img>` or b. Use a trick that involves padding (only possible if you know the aspect ratio of the image). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such thing as `background-width` in CSS. You're thinking of `background-size`, which should do exactly what you're describing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: And more specifically `background-size: cover` to fill the element without skewing the proportions.

Comment: I apologize I meant "background-size" but it's still not working correctly.  It doesn't show the image unless a fixed height is set such as in my code above.  Also "background-size:cover" doesn't scale the image at all.

Comment: @AnthonyRusso show us a jsFiddle, then, so we can see what it's doing.