# html 5 video full width with special height

Tags: html, video

I am trying to get an video on the startpage which is full width but not full height but it just does not work. It always scales down if I set the height.

```
#video_startpage {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1000;
    min-width:100%;
    max-height:400px;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxz43sga/#&togetherjs=yrnrdNEaIu

Comment: Just set the `height` to `400px` instead of `max-height`

Comment: does not change anything :(

Comment: I just noticed that when checking the fiddle, I think the `video` element resizes accordingly with a 16:9 aspect ratio

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you out on keeping the container the right width to contain a 400px height video: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12121309/2224331

Comment: If you click the white area on the sides of the video, you see that `video` element has actually 100% width but video itself does not fit to it so what you want is I dont think possible

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this! Works like charm.

```
<div id="videoarea">

<video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop id="video_startpage" >
  <source src="demo3.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>



#videoarea {
height:70%;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#video_startpage {
z-index:-9999}
```