# Scale div with fixed aspect ratio (height given)

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I'm looking for a way to keep the aspect ratio of a div fixed. I already found posts like this:

- [Responsively change div size keeping aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio)
- [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

But these posts always expect the width to be given. I would like to specify a fixed ratio and then specify *either* `height` *or* `width`.

**Examples:**

```
<div class=fixed_ratio style="width: 50px;"></div>
<div class=fixed_ratio style="height: 50px;"></div>
```

Let's say the `fixed_ratio`-class uses a fixed ratio of 1:5. The two lines above should result in two `div`'s (*50px/250px, 10px/50px*).

Is this even possible without javascript?

Comment: Given a width - you can produce a height of a specific aspect ratio... but given a height to produce a width - I don't think this is possible without javascript