# Which padding-top value for which width/height ratio?

Tags: css

A common method to preserve width/height ratio is to [apply a padding-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio) and the typical example is `padding-top: 56.25%;` for 16:9 ratio. But how is this calculated? What if I want a 10:5, 5:5 or some other ratio?

Comment: 100 devided by 16, then multiplied bij 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting an element with 100% width inside a “responsive” percentage-based-width parent element. You can then declare a percentage for bottom or top padding based on the ratio required. 
Formula to calculate percentage based on different aspect ratios:

```
C% = ( 100 / A ) * B
```

So for 16:9 (where 16 is A and 9 is B):

```
C% = ( 100 / 16 ) * 9 = 56.25%
```

And that’s all there is to it!

Here are some of the percentages for common aspect ratios:

```
75% = 4:3
66.66% = 3:2
62.5% = 8:5
```