# CSS Cannot keep aspect-ratio of div (padding-top not working)

Tags: html, css, padding, aspect-ratio

I don't know how but I've been at this for hours and can't figure it out.

I'm trying to make a div have a fixed aspect ratio of `1:1`, but the `padding-top` trick just isn't working.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
  <div/><div/><div/><div/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0px;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

Can anyone figure what I am doing wrong?

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ajpgbc0L/

Expected result: http://jsfiddle.net/ajpgbc0L/2/

**EDIT: I should have made it clear that the width could be anything**

Comment: euh, and since you div has a fixed width why bothering with padding? simply set the needed height

Comment: I should have made it clear that the width could be anything...

Comment: [It is absolute a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css), whether you use 100% or not. Just read through the answers and you'll find those using a wrapper, which is what is needed, or a pseudo element, which is another solution also shown in the dupe.

Comment: @LGSon let's add more dup link then .. people don't check all the answer, don't check the related question, don't read comments, etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif Great...and do, as someone (or queue) reopened this after I closed it.

Comment: in case you still don't agree, here is an answer like the one you accepted : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12121309/8620333

Comment: @LGSon it's wasn't someone, it's seems the reopen queue and most of the users aren't active on the CSS tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a wrapper element around it with a set width will allow you to achieve the desired result:

```
<div class="test__outer">
  <div class="test">
    <div/><div/><div/><div/>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.test {
  height: 0px;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.test__outer {
  width: 50px;
}
```

This is because precent padding is calculated, based on the width of the containing block, not the block you are setting padding on: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding#Values

Comment: Wow, thanks! I don't know how I made that mistake