# Embedding a responsive Vimeo video

Tags: html, css, vimeo

I don't understand why removing the styling from the built in div's of the embed breaks the video. I've added custom css to fit the responsive design for my website but it just doesn't go to the full size that I need. I put the script for the api at the top of my page in case you wondered where I had put it

I've added a red outline to the video box to show where it should be filling.

```
 <!-- video -->
    <div class="video-inner-container">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/644944833?h=bbb92c5056&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

css:

```
/* video */
 .video-inner-container{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  outline: red 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }

iframe{
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiPY0.png)

Comment: You need to size the iframe to match the aspect ratio of the video, otherwise Vimeo pads inside of it.

Comment: how could I do this? I thought giving it a width of 100% inside a div would do the job

Comment: Use the `padding-top` (or `padding-bottom`) trick. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12121309/203130