# HTML Coding to fit screen and image mapping

Tags: html, mapping, screen, resolution

I'm making a really simple website, just to practice, since I plan on going into this field.
I have a 27" desktop monitor, and the website looks great on it. When I checked it on my brother's laptop, 19", it looked awful because the width did not fit the screen. So I changed the code and put width="100%" . While the page looked good on each computer monitor, the links were not clickable. I figured this was due to the Image Mapping that I had added to the code.

Since I am fairly new to HTML coding, I was hoping to get some help on this site from someone who knows what they are doing.

MY QUESTION: How do I change my code to fit all screen sizes as well as not changing the Image Mapping to make the links clickable. Here is my code:

```
<center> 

<font face="verdana" size="1" color="black"> 

<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49806835/freakinwhatever/googlefrive.jpg" width="100%" usemap="#ImageMap1"> 


<div id="inlineframe" style="width:1274px; height:944px; position:absolute; left:289px; top:203px; z-index:1; overflow:auto;" usemap="#ImageMap1"> 
<iframe src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49806835/freakinwhatever/index.html" name="inlineframe" width=100% height=100% border="0" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 allowtransparency="true"></iframe> 

<map id="ImageMap1" name="ImageMap1">
<area shape="rect"  coords="54,216,261,338" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49806835/freakinwhatever/info.html" target="inlineframe" />
<area shape="rect" coords="44,553,264,678" href="" target="inlineframe" />
<area shape="rect" coords="41,961,261,1084" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49806835/freakinwhatever/specialmessage.html" target="inlineframe" />
</map>

</font> 
</center>
```

Comment: For starters don't use `font` and `map` if you plan to become a pro web developer/designer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is a responsive [jQuery plugin](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html).  Link found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844399/responsive-image-map).