# Image Map Not Working with ERB/HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am trying to put an image map into my app and I have the following erb code:

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
    <!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
    <%= image_tag "Remote.png", style: "width: 200px", usemap: "#image-map", alt: "Remote control menu.  Yes, you get to hold it." %>

    <map name="image-map">
        <area target="" alt="BBQ" title="BBQ" href="<%= url_for home_bbq_path %>" coords="241,595,103" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Jokes" title="Jokes" href="<%= url_for home_jokes_path %>" coords="511,587,95" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Memory Enhancer" title="Memory Enhancer" href="#" coords="786,580,106" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Gift Helper" title="Gift Helper" href="#" coords="259,866,105" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Grey Bottom Middle" title="Grey Bottom Middle" href="#" coords="521,856,102" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Grey Bottom Right" title="Grey Bottom Right" href="#" coords="784,868,97" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="My Mancard" title="My Mancard" href="<%= url_for edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %>" coords="241,315,140" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Sign In" title="Sign In" href="<%= url_for new_user_session_path %>" coords="669,234,909,410" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="Green Left Top" title="Green Left Top" href="#" coords="262,1224,92" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Middle Top" title="Green Middle Top" href="#" coords="516,1205,89" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Right Top" title="Green Right Top" href="#" coords="771,1212,93" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Left Bottom" title="Green Left Bottom" href="#" coords="268,1421,97" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Middle Bottom" title="Green Middle Bottom" href="#" coords="520,1409,91" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Right Bottom" title="Green Right Bottom" href="#" coords="767,1417,92" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Sign Out" title="Sign Out" href="#" coords="788,1614,76" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Menu" title="Menu" href="#" coords="255,1618,73" shape="circle">
    </map>
  </div>
```

When I look at the inspect source of the page it renders to:

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
    <!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
    <img style="width: 200px" usemap="#image-map" alt="Remote control menu.  Yes, you get to hold it." src="/assets/Remote-4f484678a9b3452f30cec85b33c1abf34aa0a74ef9c933b9c42d40a823c59b30.png" />

    <map name="image-map">
        <area target="" alt="BBQ" title="BBQ" href="/home/bbq" coords="241,595,103" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Jokes" title="Jokes" href="/home/jokes" coords="511,587,95" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Memory Enhancer" title="Memory Enhancer" href="#" coords="786,580,106" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Gift Helper" title="Gift Helper" href="#" coords="259,866,105" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Grey Bottom Middle" title="Grey Bottom Middle" href="#" coords="521,856,102" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Grey Bottom Right" title="Grey Bottom Right" href="#" coords="784,868,97" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="My Mancard" title="My Mancard" href="/users/edit.1" coords="241,315,140" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Sign In" title="Sign In" href="/users/sign_in" coords="669,234,909,410" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="Green Left Top" title="Green Left Top" href="#" coords="262,1224,92" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Middle Top" title="Green Middle Top" href="#" coords="516,1205,89" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Right Top" title="Green Right Top" href="#" coords="771,1212,93" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Left Bottom" title="Green Left Bottom" href="#" coords="268,1421,97" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Middle Bottom" title="Green Middle Bottom" href="#" coords="520,1409,91" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Green Right Bottom" title="Green Right Bottom" href="#" coords="767,1417,92" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Sign Out" title="Sign Out" href="#" coords="788,1614,76" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Menu" title="Menu" href="#" coords="255,1618,73" shape="circle">
    </map>
  </div>
```

The image appears but it does not seem to have any links.  Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your coords are ok?

Comment: @meves, I used an online generator to get the coordinates, but the links aren't appearing anywhere on the image.  If the coordinates were wrong wouldn't they just be in the wrong places?

Comment: Can you show us the image? Or create a plunker with an example? Because I'm not seeing the problem..

Comment: @meves, I updated the code with a simpler coordinate system, but the problem persists.  Also the staging link is https://bearded-hockey-79768.herokuapp.com/ so you can see the problem.  It's the remote on the bottom right of the index page.

Comment: I found your problem, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem.

You set a fixed width to img (`style="width: 200px"`) and your coords is to full image size.

You will need to use a resized image on your generator, and avoid the css width.

Comment: Unfortunately no change with that new/changed line.

Comment: Excellent! Just out of curiosity, is it possible to do an image map on a responsive image?

Comment: I think it is possible only with javascript.. I saw here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844399/responsive-image-map

Comment: Okay, that change got it so that the link appeared, but now I'm getting `Bad Request

bad URI '/%3C%=%20url_for%20edit_user_registration_path(current_user)%20%%3E'.
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.4/2015-12-16) at elizabeths-macbook-pro.local:3000`.   Any thoughts?

Comment: Ahhh, figured it out.  Thank you!  It works perfectly now!