# Shall I use map tag in html5 to put link on images ?

Tags: html

So A huge classic is tu put a link on image.
The old fashioned way is to do something like

```
<a href="wtv">
    <img src="wvt">
</a>
```

Since the introduction of `<map>` we can do something like this :

```
<map name="exemple-map-1">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0 100%,100%" href="https://developer.mozilla.org" target="_blank" />
</map>
<img usemap="#exemple-map-1" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/14546/map.png">
```

But is this good practice?

Comment: if you want to target only some part of image then go with map and if full image then use anchor

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** In HTML5, if the `id` attribute of the `<map>` tag is also specified, it **must** have the same value as the `name` attribute.

I would prefer using a `position` instead of that for better compatibility. This is just my view. An example of it would be:

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap img {
  display: block;
}

.wrap .click {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 27px;
  top: 105px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#" class="click"></a>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD4Z1.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

**Note:** I have added a background tint to show the `<a>` on top of the image.

Comment: Good approach.. But if someone want this to be responsive?

Comment: @SahilDhir Curious to know, so are Maps responsive? _checks it out..._ ... *and finds out it's not!* -- [HTML5 Maps are not Responsive!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7844399)

Comment: I think there is a plugin available to make image maps responsive.. But I am just asking how to make your solution responsive...

Comment: Yeah I usually do this like that and you can have a responsive pattern with % and calcul anyway.