# HTML - make images join

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of images that are right next to each other to form a navigation bar. There are no gaps so it looks like one image while being able to make certain areas of it clickable and others not. How do I make it so if the navigation bar is too long for the window it gets smaller instead of some of the images going on a new line?

**HTML/CSS:**

```css
.navbar-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <img src="Images/NavBar1.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <a href="Home.html">
    <img src="Images/NavBar2.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  </a>
  <img src="Images/NavBar3.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <a href="Information.html">
    <img src="Images/NavBar4.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  </a>
  <img src="Images/NavBar5.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <img src="Images/NavBar6.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <img src="Images/NavBar7.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <a href="Schedule.html">
    <img src="Images/NavBar8.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  </a>
  <img src="Images/NavBar9.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">
    <img src="Images/NavBar10.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  </a>
  <img src="Images/NavBar11.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
</center>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe you can share some code?

Comment: Please add a code example. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <center> tags are obsolete in html5. use margin:0 auto to center instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to prevent the linebreak with multiple images, you may want to take a look at the possibility to define clickable areas on a single image. You can define a map with different clickable areas. Take a look at the example below, where only the area around the text is actually clickable:

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" usemap="#map">

<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="100,150,500,250" href="#">
</map>
```

You can also define different shapes and sizes, for a better understanding, just take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)

#### Please also note

If you define coordinates as pixels, this can lead to different clickable areas, if you resize the image. There is another question at StackOverflow, with a helpful discussion on [how to create responsive image maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844399/responsive-image-map)

Comment: Would I need to change the coordinates if the image is scaled, or would that be scaled automatically?

Comment: If the size of the image changes, you also need to adjust the coordinates. In the SO Thread I linked, they mention a jQuery Plugin that automatically adjusts the values, maybe this could help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i got what you are trying to do but check this and let me if it works for you
jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nves359o/)

```
<div class="my-navbar">
 <center>
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <a href="Home.html">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  </a>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <a href="Information.html">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  </a>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <a href="Schedule.html">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  </a>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
  </a>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/25/08/03/the-button-859350_1280.png" alt="" class="navbar-button" />
 </center>

 </div>

.navbar-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 10%;
  float:left;
  width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.navbar-button {
   margin: 0 10px !important;
   padding: 0;
   display: inline block;
   text-align: center;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: 10%;
}
```