# Extracting Link text coordinates from an image in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, area

I have a `.png` image with different colors differentiating text from Links. I need to extract the link text from this image and convert it to a clickable Link within that image i.e either I extract the text based on its color or I simply mark the area which is clickable. I also need to keep in mind that this doesnt break on different resolutions or browsers window sizes, i.e. clickable area isnt clickable due to applied CSS.

I have tried creating a map.

```
<img src="workplace.png" alt="Workplace" useMap="#workmap" style={{maxwidth:`99%`}}>

<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" href="coffee.htm">
</map>
```

which basically marks the coords of a clickable area within the image and map to a link.

I am also applying `style={{maxwidth:`99%`}}` to the `img` tag so that the image fits within the browser window to avoid scrolling to the right because the image is big. However the moment I apply `style={{maxwidth:`99%`}}` on my `img`, the coords changes.

Is there a better solution to this? Is there a way for me to find these link text dynamically (through extracting the content based on its color difference) and then convert them to links instead of first finding the coords and then just hardcoding them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844399/responsive-image-map

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking about with the rest of it. _“I need to extract the link text from this image and convert it to a clickable Link within that image.”_ - are you actually talking about analysing the _content_ of that image here? Show an example, please. How would you know what to link _to_, if you only read the link _text_ from that image?

Comment: I made some edits. Hope it clarifies the confusion.